# Variable not found. Referencing objects from another class

Tags: java

Background:

I'm creating a basic download centre on a concurrent server.

I create file objects in the `Server class` under a main method

```
File[] files = {
    new File("1. Program", "myProgram.jar"),
    new File("2. Image", "myPicture.jpg"),
    new File("3. Book", "myBook.txt")};
```

This references to the `File class` where I create constructors and getters.

```
class File {

    private String option;
    private String fileName;


    public File(String option, String fileName) {
        this.option = option;
        this.fileName= fileName;
    }

    public String getOption() {
        return option;
    }


    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void getFileOptions(File[] files) {
        for (File f : files) {
            System.out.printf("The option is %s\n", f.getOption());
        }
    } 
}
```

I am attempting to call the `getFileOptions` method from my `ServerState class`.

```
theOutput= File.getFileOptions(files);
```

The output is a string that is returned to a client.

My IDE says that `(files)` cannot be found. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Cam I not return results to a class where the object wasn't initially created?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Are you trying to reference `files` from a different class? Because you can't do that if it's not declared static.

Comment: It's worse than that, Jivings.  If that were the problem, he'd be wondering why `Server.files` failed.  In a way, it's impressive.

Comment: Show the surrounding code where you put the call to `getFileOptions`.  For starters, if that's in your `ServerState` class you need an instance of `File` to call `getFileOptions`, or `getFileOptions` needs to be static.

Comment: This might be a long shot but are you sure you don't have `import java.io.File;` somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I have moved the File objects into the `ServerState class` and access the options using             `String theOutput = files[0].toString() + files[1].toString() + files[2].toString();` by calling a `toString()` method from the `File class` that also contain the object constructors, getters and setters.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you have 3 classes mentioned here

Server(main) class which has a files variable which is an array of File objects.

File which is your object class.

And ServerState class which is where you are trying to do:

```
theOutput= File.getFileOptions(files);
```

correct?

You cannot create an object in the server class and use it in the ServerState class unless you pass a reference to it or something, in which case we need more context in your example to help you. Might be a good idea to read that scope tutorial posted above.

Answer (score -2):

The `files` you defined in one method of one class has absolutely nothing to do with the `files` you attempt to reference in another method of another class. If it were otherwise, don't you think your use would conflict with another programmer's prior use of the variable somewhere in the bowels of the SDK?  Or that you would've already been told to only ever use 'safe' names like myNameThisClassFiles?

Anyway, [a tutorial](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html).

Comment: Illiterates: the problem corrected by the other answer is only one of the OP's problems, and it is far less disasterous than the problem I correct here - which is also the problem expressly asked about.  But if another one of you downvote this answer, I can wash my hands of the OP and get a badge.